# How to move a movieclip in composition

Tags: node-editor, video-sequence-editor, movie-clip-editor, chromakey

I have a composition of two videos. I used keying nodes, movieclip and alpha over. The video 1 is a loop that I will use as a background with dimensions of 1280x720.
The video 2 is a video with chromakey of 640x640.
I have composed them, but I would like that the video2 could have a transfer animation from the left side to the right side from frame 0 to frame 200. Is it possible to make that?

Comment: What do you mean with "transfer"?

Comment: sorry, I mean translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *Transform node* (*Add > Distort > Transform*) and animate the values for X (horizontal)

Answer (score 0):

The add-on mentioned here will pop up the animation menu with the shortcut key 'I' or it can be accessed through the menu:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/180382/37272