# Video editing transform strip offset and crop in Preview window

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor, transforms, video, effects

Is there a gizmo that lets me transform a strip position and crop directly in the Preview window?

This would be much easier than using the side pane menus.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the 2.83 alpha, grab this add-on and use the transform tools in the toolbar:
https://github.com/tin2tin/VSE_Transform_Tools

[image]