# Transform a Strip without crop and distortion

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transforms, 2d

The problem is the ImageStrip has no scale parameter. That means it is so complicated to place an image within the output format. Let's say the output format is 1920*1080 and I have a photo which is 3000*2000. I would like to have something like this:

[image]

Since there is no scale parameters built in the ImageStrip I would have a very hard time to do the math and place the picture using adjustment/transform/crop parameters.
To use a transform strip also problematic because the original picture would be cropped. So I have to have the distorted image (without crop) as a starting point and do the math to get the correct non-uniform scale values to get the correct/original image aspect.
Both solutions are definitely not interactive. If I willing to change the scale I have to recalculate the correct crop or non-uniform scale values (back to the 90s :) )
So any ideas about that?

Comment: (Every time I write this as an answer it gets downvoted so I won't do it again...) You are correct: the VSE is indeed from the 90's and has not evolved much. The design and responsiveness of the app cannot meet the needs of video makers of this century. Just use a dedicated video editing app and be happy. Blender is a superb 3d content creation app use it for what it is good for.

Comment: For now use the Transform Tools add-on(tools in the Preview Toolbar): https://github.com/doakey3/VSE_Transform_Tools Gif: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/180382/37272
Very soon this patch will be committed to solve the transform problems(then you can test it in 2.91 beta): https://developer.blender.org/D8393